# how can I import llama in python

Tags: python, pip, llama-index

I tried to install llama with pip:

> pip install llama

But I got:

```
Collecting llama
  Using cached llama-0.1.1.tar.gz (387 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "D:\python\python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "D:\python\python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "D:\python\python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\spark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-87x4skmg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\spark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-87x4skmg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\spark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-87x4skmg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 488, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\spark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-87x4skmg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
      NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Looks like the main problem is 'execfile' is not available.

> NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined

I also tried to install with pycodestyle, but error is still there.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [MCVE], also take a [tour].

Answer (score 1):

`execfile` was removed in Python 3. The code seems to be Python2-only. At the https://pypi.org/project/llama/ the only supported version is Python 2.7 (see the bottom of the left column).

What package do you want to install? There're many llamas at PyPI: https://pypi.org/search/?q=llama

Answer (score -1):

Please use:

```
pip install lamini
```

You can follow the instructions from [here](https://lamini-ai.github.io/Start/setup/)

Comment: This actually fixes the following import error: from llama import BasicModelRunner

Answer (score -1):

The solution that worked for me came from GitHub: https://github.com/imartinez/privateGPT/issues/113

intall `llama-cpp-python > 0.1.53` for Python 3.11